# Uploaded the Text File to The src>application but won't read it. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: java

```
File file = new File("student_info1.txt");

// if file is not found, report and exit program
if (!file.exists()) {
    System.out.println("File can not be found! Exiting program...");
    System.exit(1);
}

// open a scanner object to read from file
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: by the way text file name is also "student_info.txt".

Comment: Please add any additional information to the original question rather than as a comment. Also, you say the text file name is "student_info.txt" but in the code you have "student_info1.txt"

Comment: Check, what `file.getAbsolutePath()` returns. Possibly the current working directory does not suit your needs and the file path is simply wrong. Also storing files in the source directories is bad practice for any files that should not be included as resource. Resources on the other hand should not be accessed via `File`...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read the file by repeatedly calling `Scanner#nextLine();` on `input`.

```
while (!input.hasNextLine()) {
    String lineOfText = input.nextLine();
    // Do something with your line of text here.
}
```